# ansible delegate_to variable undefined

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a problem where I'm trying to delegate facts to a group of hosts. I have a master node generating a value, and I want to ensure my group of "workers" has access to that value (rather than targeting the master via hostname).

ansible 2.7.9
vagrant 2.2.4

VagrantFile

```
ansible_groups = {
    "local" => [],
    "swarm" => [],
    "swarm-master-first" => [],
    "swarm-master" => [],
    "swarm-worker" => []
  }

  (1..num_masters).each do |i|
    ansible_groups["local"].push("swarm_master#{i}")
    ansible_groups["swarm"].push("swarm_master#{i}")
    if i == 1
      ansible_groups["swarm-master-first"].push("swarm_master#{i}")
    end
    ansible_groups["swarm-master"].push("swarm_master#{i}")
  end
  (1..num_workers).each do |i|
    ansible_groups["local"].push("swarm_worker#{i}")
    ansible_groups["swarm"].push("swarm_worker#{i}")
    ansible_groups["swarm-worker"].push("swarm_worker#{i}")
  end

  (1..num_masters).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "swarm_master#{i}" do |swarm_master|
      swarm_master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.1#{i}"
      swarm_master.vm.hostname = "swarmmaster#{i}"
      swarm_master.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
          vb.name = "swarm-master#{i}"
      end
      swarm_master.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
        ansible.become = true
        ansible.become_user = "root"
        ansible.groups = ansible_groups
      end
    end
  end

  (1..num_workers).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "swarm_worker#{i}" do |node|
      node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.2#{i}"
      node.vm.hostname = "swarmworker#{i}"
      node.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
          vb.name = "swarm-worker#{i}"
      end
      node.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
        ansible.become = true
        ansible.become_user = "root"
        ansible.groups = ansible_groups
      end
    end
  end
end
```

resulting in an inventory:

```
# Generated by Vagrant

swarm_master1 ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_port=2222 ansible_user='vagrant' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/Users/dmcminn/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key'
swarm_worker1 ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_port=2200 ansible_user='vagrant' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/Users/dmcminn/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key'

[local]
swarm_master1
swarm_worker1

[swarm]
swarm_master1
swarm_worker1

[swarm-master-first]
swarm_master1

[swarm-master]
swarm_master1

[swarm-worker]
swarm_worker1
```

playbook.yml

```
- hosts: swarm-master-first
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        swarm_token: "TEST"
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      delegate_facts: True
      with_items: "{{ groups['swarm-worker'] }}"
    #- debug: var=swarm_token

- hosts: swarm-worker
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug: var=swarm_token
```

output

```
PLAY [swarm-master-first] ******************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [swarm_master1 -> 127.0.0.1] => (item=swarm_worker1)

...

PLAY [swarm-worker] ************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [swarm_worker1]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [swarm_worker1] => {
    "swarm_token": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The scope of a variable is the playbook. Scope of the variable "swarm_token" is the 1st playbook. 2nd playbook knows nothing about "swarm_token".

Comment: Ok, I must have misunderstood the usage of this then. Any suggestions for doing what I need here? i.e. one group generates some output, I want another group of hosts to utilize the output in a diff role.

Comment: An option would be to store the shared variables in a file (created for example by template module) and then "include_vars" where needed.

Comment: I think my problem here is, along the lines of what you mentioned, where vagrant is executing the ansible playbook separately in two different runs. Do you have any idea how to tell vagrant to wait for all machines to be up then execute the playbook once?

Comment: "to wait for all machines to be up" is not practical. Ansible is more a tool that defines a state of a system that a procedural language. IIUIC an option would be to define the states of the "masters" and then proceed with the "workers". [Best practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices) might help with some tips.